# equivalent code in wpf

Tags: wpf, vb.net, datagrid, datagridview

In Winforms I used the below code to select the specific item in DataGridView.

```
If DGView.Rows(row).Cells(0).Value.StartsWith(txtBoxInDGView.Text, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) Then
    DGView.Rows(row).Selected = True
    DGView.CurrentCell = DGView.SelectedCells(0)
End If
```

Can anyone give the equivalent code for WPF DataGrid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WPF is more data-driven than WinForms. It means it's better to work with objects (that represent your data) than to deal with UI elements.

You should have a collection that is the items source of the data grid. In the same data context, you should have a property that will hold the selected item (same type as the items in the collection). All properties should notify change.

Considering you have `MyItem` class for each row in data grid, the code would be something like this:

In the class that is the data context of your data grid:

```
public ObservableCollection<MyItem> MyCollection {get; set;}
public MyItem MySelectedItem {get; set;} //Add change notification

private string _myComparisonString;
public string MyComparisonString 
{
    get{return _myComparisonString;}
    set
    {
        if _myComparisonString.Equals(value) return;
        //Do change notification here
        UpdateSelection();
    }
}
.......
private void UpdateSelection()
{
    MyItem theSelectedOne = null;
    //Do some logic to find the item that you need to select
    //this foreach is not efficient, just for demonstration
    foreach (item in MyCollection)
    {
        if (theSelectedOne == null && item.SomeStringProperty.StartsWith(MyComparisonString))
        {
            theSelectedOne = item;
        }
    }

    MySelectedItem = theSelectedOne;
}
```

In your XAML, you'd have a TextBox and a DataGrid, similar to this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding MyComparisonString, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
....
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding MySelectedItem}"/>
```

This way, your logic is independent from your UI. As long as you have change notification - the UI will update the properties and the properties will affect the UI.

[Treat code above as a pseudo-code, I'm not on my dev machine currently]